# Postgres 9.3.14 showing duplicate values for primary key

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We are facing duplicate rows issue with postgres 9.3.14.

Tried with below options as well:

```
SET LOCAL enable_indexscan = off;
SET LOCAL enable_bitmapscan = off;
SET LOCAL enable_indexonlyscan = off;
```

With these options also it is not displaying duplicate records.

But if you try the command to fetch duplicate records (Eg cmd: `SELECT name, email, COUNT(*) FROM users GROUP BY name, email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`) it is showing it has 2 records for the same primary key.

But if you try to fetch the same row from the table,(eg: `SELECT * from users where name=<output from previous command> and users=<output from previous command>`) it is showing only 1 row.

This issue is seen at customer site. Is there any bug reported for this issue?

Comment: Sounds like an index problem. `reindex`

Comment: We will check the `reindex` option. But what might be the reason behind such weird behavior? I checked triggers as well